# Tesseract.NET in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ocr, tesseract

Do you know of step by step guide of how to use bins and dlls in http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/

I spent 2 days trying to use this by when compiling i am being asked for a dll that do not exist in the zip file i downloaded from the site.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the name of missing dll?

Comment: Does it have to be Tesseract.NET? Here's a .NET example for another (web-API-based) OCR solution: http://snipt.org/lOgh/

Answer (score 2):

You need the Leptonica DLL for Windows.  You can download it from http://www.leptonica.com/download.html, or direct link to the specific zip is [here](http://www.leptonica.com/source/vs2008-1.67.zip).  You need to copy the lib & include folders into the Google Tesseract vs2008 folder (ie, create vs2008\lib and vs2008\include).

Answer (score 2):

1. download the binaries here:  http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/bin.zip
2. select the project and rightclick in the project explorer → Add reference → Browse...
3. select the dll version that is compatible with your build settings (x86 or x64) see the properties of your project
4. do a rebuild

Remove all installations of the tesseract bins from 3.0 also cleanup your registry (took me hours to find this one out).

Answer (score 1):

[VietOCR.NET](http://vietocr.sf.net) is a working program of tessnet2 library. It is an open-source application.

Comment: Actually `VietOcr` performs command line calls to `tesseract.exe`. I prefer to use this method though because it calls for less hassle.

Comment: @Laurence: VietOCR.NET v2.0.x uses tessnet2. Because a Tess 3.0 DLL was not available at the time, v3.0 used command-line process to invoke tesseract.exe; however, v3.1 will integrate a new Tess 3.01 DLL (tesseractdotnet).