# Fast OCR in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, ocr

I'm creating an application that finds all of the text in a picture regardless of text size or font (whithin reason, Just the basic monospaced and default windows fonts).  I tried making my own but it was slow and very unreliable.  I need it to work fast (as close to instant (give or take 1 or 2 seconds)).  I have to run it on images 1000+x1000+ (Nothing more than 1500).  I have to take the values of the text and the position of it in the image.

Thanks if you can help!

I'm using VB.net, just so you know.

Comment: Fast and accurate are *very* incompatible goals.  Set realistic targets.

Comment: No they aren't, they're just two sides of the magic triangle. You can have it fast, you can have it accurate, you can have it cheap. Pick any two <g>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you look into the [Tesseract OCR library](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) (currently maintained by Google) which also has a .NET binding [here](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/) and a related SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424246/tesseract-net-in-c).